# How to use media screen in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am using a background image for a navbar in responsive design.

```
.navbar {
   background-image: url(http://www.sample.com/images/bg.png);
   background-repeat: repeat-x;

  }
```

i want the background image to turnoff at 960 px and use a gradient background.

```
    @media (min-width: 960px) {
.navbar {
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f72a8 0%, #040aa5 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4f72a8 0%, #040aa5 100%);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 filter:    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
 (startColorstr='#ffffffff',   endColorstr='#ffdfdfdf', GradientType=0);
}
}
```

I get the gradient but the original background image does not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reset the background at the beginning. This should work for you.

```
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    .navbar {
        background-image: none;

        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f72a8 0%, #040aa5 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4f72a8 0%, #040aa5 100%);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        filter:    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
            (startColorstr='#ffffffff',   endColorstr='#ffdfdfdf', GradientType=0);
    }
}
```